# Filter tables in SSMS with two conditions

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to filter e.g. tables in Object Explorer in SSMS based on a `or` condition. That is I want to filter all tables which either have "this" or "that" (see below)
[image]

Comment: according to https://bertwagner.com/2018/06/26/filtering-tables-procedures-and-other-objects-in-ssms/ you cannot apply complex condition

Comment: Why don't you use a sql query?

Comment: @JaimeDrq: Because I want to get an overview in Object Explorer

Comment: I haven't tried myself but you could try ('value1', 'value2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this using queries.

Examples

```
USE [YourDatabase]

-- Get all tables starting with a or b, inside schema dbo.
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables t 
WHERE (t.Name LIKE 'A%'
OR t.Name LIKE 'B%')
AND t.schema_Id = schema_id('dbo')

-- Get all Tables, views, Stored procedures, and inline table valued functions starting with A

SELECT *
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.Name LIKE 'A%'
AND o.type IN (
    'U' -- User table
    , 'V' -- Vieww
    , 'P ' -- Stored Procedure
    , 'IF' -- Inline Table valued Functions
)
```

Comment: I have wished for this for a while, since we use schemas for organizing and I want, for example both "Finance" and "Orders" but not any others. I wish there were a way to set this to persist, since I set the same filters every day.